# How to implement searching and filtering in Ionic

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am fetching data from a JSON file that's stored locally within my project. The JSON string is an array of locations, whose structure is like so:

**JSON file**

```
{
    "locations": [
        {
            "title": "ABC",
            "latitude": -1.2596551,
            "longitude": 36.7066604,
            "routes":["22","23","105","115"],
            "fare":[],
            "matatu":[]
        },
        {
            "title": "Adams Arcade",
            "latitude": -1.3004204,
            "longitude": 36.7770793,
            "routes": ["2","4W","102","24","24C","111"],
            "fare":[],
            "matatu":[]
        },
        {
            "title":"Aga Khan Hospital",
            "latitude":-1.2620125,
            "longitude":36.8186399,
            "routes":["11A","11F","106","107","116"],
            "fare":[],
            "matatu":[]
        }
    ]
}
```

Rather than filtering the data on the fly with a pipe, I have implemented a function in my `provider` to handle this. Here's the code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';

@Injectable()
export class LocationProvider {

  data: any;

  constructor(public http: Http, public geolocation: Geolocation) {

  }

  load(){

    if(this.data){
      return Promise.resolve(this.data);
    }

    return new Promise(resolve => {
        this.http.get('assets/data/locations.json').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
          this.data = this.applyHarvesine(data.locations);
          this.data.sort((locationA, locationB) => {
            return locationA.distance - locationB.distance;
          });
          resolve(this.data);
        });
    });

  }

  filterLocations(searchTerm){
    return this.data.filter((location) => {
      return location.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) > -1;
    });
  }

}
```

The `filterLocations()` function is to take in `searchTerm` and returns an array containing only the elements that match the search criteria.

Here's the `.ts` and `.html` code for the page where it is rendered.

**.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { LocationProvider } from '../../providers/location/location';
import { PlaceDetailsPage } from '../place-details/place-details';


@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-places',
  templateUrl: 'places.html',
})
export class PlacesPage {

  searchTerm: string = '';



  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public locations: LocationProvider) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.setFilteredLocations();
  }

  setFilteredLocations(){
    return this.locations.filterLocations(this.searchTerm);
  }

}
```

**.html**

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-searchbar [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" (ionInput)="setFilteredLocations()"></ion-searchbar>
    <ion-list no-lines>
        <button ion-item *ngFor="let location of locations.data">
            <ion-avatar item-left>
                <ion-icon name="pin"></ion-icon>
            </ion-avatar>
            <h2>{{location.title}}</h2>
            <p>{{location.distance}} km</p>
        </button>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

When the user types on the searchbar, `setFilteredLocation()` is called to trigger the filtering of data. The problem is, nothing happens.

Where have I gone wrong? My hunch is that something is amiss in the `setFilteredLocation()` function, but I have no clue what it is.

Is there an alternative approach to searching and filtering that doesn't involve pipes?

Comment: I don't know enough ionic to be sure but shouldn't you call `load` before `filterLocations`? Without `data` this would be the expected behaviour

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are doing it wrong.

1. You do `return this.data.filter(...)`. It has no effect to your
   origin array (`this.data`). It just return a new array and does not make change to `this.data`. See the filter [function doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
2. If you want to make change to your data you need to add: `this.data = this.data.filter(...)`. But if you do like that, you will fall in other mistake. Your `this.data` will lost some element after filter and it can not be revert when you reset the filter.

So you should do like that:
In your component:

```
allData = []; //Store all data from provider
filterData = [];//Store filtered data

ionViewDidEnter(){
  this.allData = this.locations.data;
  this.filterData = this.allData;
}

setFilteredLocations(){
    this.filterData = this.allData.filter((location) => {
      return location.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchTerm.toLowerCase()) > -1;
    });
}
```

And in your template use filterData in `ngFor`:

```
<button ion-item *ngFor="let location of filterData">
```

Answer (score 2):

Yo didn't send the `$event` here. So try as shown below.

*.html*

```
 <ion-searchbar [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" 
(ionInput)="setFilteredLocations($event)"></ion-searchbar>
```

*.ts*

```
 setFilteredLocations(ev: any){
    let val = ev.target.value;

    if (val && val.trim() !== '') {
      return this.locations.filterLocations(val);
    }

  }
```

You can see the [**official sample code here**](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/tree/master/demos/src/searchbar).

Comment: What argument should I give in the function `this.setFilteredLocations()` that's nested in `ionViewDidLoad()`?

Comment: You don't need it. You can remove it.

Comment: I've looked into it. It's not working. Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you see this? https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/tree/master/demos/src/searchbar

Comment: Try to implement simple one first.After that refactor the code.Try above doc's sample.